# Databricks spark job without progress

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Well, I am trying to run a job that uses Spark on a Databricks cluster.

Sometimes it gets no progress and keeps running for ever without any error, the cluster keeps running indefinitely, check out the following logs. I already realized that it might happens when there is 0 workers in the cluster. But in this case, I am trying to run with 3 worker nodes, and get the same problem.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: eventLog.rolloverIntervalSeconds
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
```

Any idea of what might it be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the following config from my spark initializer.

```
.config('spark.driver.host', '127.0.0.1')
```